# Dynamic Text replacement for PPC Campaigns

Tags: seo, google-ads-api, pay-per-click

Stumbled across this: http://get.unbounce.com/dynamic-text-replacement/

Seems to be a wysiwg landing page creator. So I was just wondering if it's possible to do Dynamic Text replacement normally? Pretty much just need 1 Landing page that will have text (keywords) change depending on what the user searched from search engine. An dif possible also have images change out depending on what the user searched.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: The problem is likely to be that the dynamic replacement is not visible to the AdsBot. You will likely suffer a reduced quality score. It is usually better to have a custom page for each group of keywords that a page responds to, IME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdWords lets you use what is called "[ValueTrack](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en-GB)" in the click-through URLs for your ads.  So you could have your clickthrough URL in AdWords as "http://www.example.com?keyword={keyword}" then when someone clicks on your ad, AdWords will replace {keyword} with the actual keyword from the search, or for display ads the best-match keyword.

You could then have some code on your site (could be client or server side - you could do it with Javascript) to look for the keyword query string parameter from the URL, extract the value of that parameter, then place it into a  onto your site.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Matt. But would you agree with Jezc that this would cause a reduction in quality score?

Comment: I dont think it would cause a *reduction*, but it is true that the Google crawler will not see the same page that your visitors might, and so the page may not seem as relevant to Google as it does to your users. I'd run an A/B test of static landing pages vs dynamic and see what the QS impact is as well as what the conversion rate impact is - you might pay more per click, but as the landing page experience is better for the users (regardless of what Google thinks), they may convert more and give a lower CPA overall.  Worth a test I think!

Comment: Thanks for the great information Matt! Will test this out and see what happens.

Comment: Matt, I tried using example.com/page-name?keyword={keyword} on adwords but when searched on google, it's still showing the link as ?keyword={keyword} and not the actual keyword that was being searched. Any further insights on this?